# Defining a test that requires two steps to pass in rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

Is there a better way to do this?

```
describe '#reset_all' do
  it 'should reset foo for all objects' do
    manager.iterate_all
    manager.reset_all
    obj1.foo.should == 0
    obj2.foo.should == 0
  end
end
```

It seems messy because the second "should ==" line gives me a syntax warning of "useless use of == in void context", and I also only get one error if both requirements fail.  But it doesn't seem important enough to make a separate test.

Comment: Is foo an integer that should be equivalent to 0? It also might help to provide a little more context as to what you are trying to test. In general it's fine to have more than one assertion per test case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with

```
(obj1.foo == 0 && obj2.foo == 0).should be_true
```

or with

```
[obj1, obj2].all?{|o| o.foo == 0}.should be_true
```

Having more than one failure reported for one test case is basically not possible.